# Lost Xdebug.ini file while installing Xdebug

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug, lampp

Accidentally i lost `xdebug.ini` file in `/etc/php5/conf.d` folder. How to get back that while i am trying to install xdebug using `apt-get`,it's giving an note like below.

```
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

I searched for this in google, i am able to find only one useful reply. That i can't understand how to do so i am pasting that also here, so please suggest me how to proceed.

```
I lost my xdebug.ini file on my ubuntu slice. What happened was that I had accidentally installed xdebug via apt-get as well as pecl. I was removing the pecl installation, which also removed the ini file. I then tried reinstalling through apt-get, but i get the message: 

Setting up php5-xdebug (2.0.3-1) ...
Not replacing deleted config file /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini

Aaaaaarghhhh!! How do I get back my ini file??? anyone have a clue?
rubing January 2009
I just fixed this by purging xdebug using dpkg with the -P flag. And then reinstalling with apt-get. No worries!

Ah geez, it looks the whole file is just a link to the module:

zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613/xdebug.so
```

Answer (score 1):

The file that you deleted (/etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini) just contains the following line:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613/xdebug.so
```

Although the path might be different as that seems for an older PHP version - check which directory names you have under /usr/lib/php5 and use that.

Alternative options are already provided by @tetet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'apt-get install --reinstall' will do the trick for you. Otherwise touch xdebug.ini in /etc/php5/conf.d and try again, touch creates an empty file.

An alternate route is to unpack the downloaded debian package and copy the config file from there: dpkg-deb -x .

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays it's content is more like:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

Please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24658116/17532524) for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).