# How to add XDebug zend_extension to php.ini?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a VPS with cPanel WHM and am trying to enable XDebug. I installed the extension by going to `WHM -> Software -> Module Installers -> PHP Pecl -> Manage` and I confirmed it's installed by checking my `phpinfo()` page.

The next step is to enable XDebug in my php.ini file, but I'm a little confused how I should go about doing this.

Looking at php.ini in `/usr/local/lib`, I see this line at the bottom:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-6.0.0/php-5.4.x/ZendGuardLoader.so"
```

However, in WHM -> Service Configuration -> PHP Configuration Editor, there's a "zend_extension" option with this value:

```
/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so, /usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-6.0.0/php-5.4.x/ZendGuardLoader.so
```

So my question is, how should I go about adding the path to XDebug:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so
```

To php.ini? I see three ways of doing it and I don't know which is correct:

1. I could add it to the comma separated list in WHM
2. I could add it in php.ini directly, putting a comma between it and the existing value
3. I could put it on a new line in php.ini

Which way is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Highly depends on the PHP configuration (`./configure`). PHP will look in the default extension path for your `xdebug.so` extension; in which case you don't need to specify any path:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
```

Regarding new line and comma, I prefer new line because it makes it easier to remove an extension later on. My `php.ini` looks like this (example):

```
extension      = memcached.so
extension      = zopfli.so
zend_extension = opcache.so
zend_extension = xdebug.so
```

Notice the alphabetical order as well.

Comment: So it's OK to have multiple `zend_extension` lines in php.ini? When I add the xdebug line in PhpStorm, it gives the warning `Duplicate Key in Section`.

Comment: In the official [doc](https://xdebug.org/docs/install#configure-php) it is said that `"If you want to use Xdebug and OPCache together, you must have the zend_extension line for Xdebug below the line for OPCache, or in a file starting with a higher number (ie. 99-xdebug.ini vs 20-opcache.ini), otherwise they won't work properly together."`

Answer (score 1):

You can add at the bottom of the file like the following:

```
zend_extension="/absolute/path/to/xdebug.so"
```

In my case, i put it in

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
```

However
If you want to use Xdebug and OPCache together, you must have the zend_extension line for Xdebug after the line for OPCache. Otherwise, they won't work properly.
See: https://xdebug.org/docs/install