# Can't locate xdebug.so on linux

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

I'm having some problems getting xdebug running on ElementaryOS (Ubuntu 16.04.2) with php7, and Apache2.

I installed it with `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`. The install didn't report any errors. I've added

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 ; Not safe for production servers
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=true
```

to `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`.

I also need to add the xdebug.so file location like, `zend_extension="/path/to/xdebug.so"`. However, I have been unable to find xdebug.so after the install.

Does anyone know where xdebug.so is, or has the instructions changed since php7.0 was released. Most of the instructions/help seem to be for php5 online.

Thanks.

Comment: I found a similar question. Maybe it will [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24658116).

Comment: Thanks I found it, and forgot about this post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming related question, it should be on topic for https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Check xDebug is installed.

```
php -m
```

Run `locate xdebug.so`

Returns `/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so` for me, but `20151012` might change in the future.

You have to execute `sudo updatedb` if `locate` does not return anything or you've just installed locate

Comment: You have to `sudo updatedb` if `locate` does not return anything and you've just installed `locate`.

Comment: install first of all mlocate before you can use locate. For CentOs `sudo yum -y install mlocate`

Answer (score 11):

For the new versions just add xdebug file name, example:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
...
```

If it does not work use Linux find command like the following:

**`find / -name "xdebug.so"`**

What does this command do?

- Find = just find
- / = in all of directories inside / (all)
- -name "xdebug.so" = with name equal to xdebug.so

Comment: According to the official xdebug installation documentation (https://xdebug.org/docs/install) not including the full path to xdebug.so will cause problems. 

*NOTE: I don't know if this only applies to installations of xdebug using PECL*

 **Note: You should ignore any prompts to add "extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini —  this will cause problems.**

Answer (score 5):

Create a file with phpinfo(). Find the item extension_dir. There you'll see where the xdebug.so resides. Mine is:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
```