# I can't find xdebug.so

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to set up xdebug for PhpStorm. I just installed xdebug and edit php.ini file. Then I run

```
locate xdebug.so
```

But nothing happened...

I checked with `php -m`. It shows me xdebug installed but why I cannot find its location?

My OS is Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com. Ubuntu specific questions should be asked on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365973/cant-locate-xdebug-so-on-linux I found this question, so..

Comment: It doesn't matter. Admittedly there might be a gray area but it's general purpose computing and how to find a .so file, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

It should be there :

`sudo nano /etc/php7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`

The line zend_extension=xdebug.so should already be there.  Add the following lines  :

```
    zend_extension=xdebug.so
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
    xdebug.scream=0 
    xdebug.cli_color=1
    xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

I have ubuntu 16  but it should not have changed.

After, 
`sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

so that the changes take effect